# How to provision environment specific application configuration with kubernetes

Tags: provisioning, kubernetes

We are moving our ruby microservices to kubernetes and we used to hold environment specific configuration in the `config/application.yml`. With kubernetes, you can create environment specific files for each service, e.g. `config/kubernetes/production.yml` etc.

While kubernetes pod configuration file is able to hold environmental variables, it seems that you cannot really hold structured data in there.

For an example, in `application.yml` we have

```
development: &development
  process:
    notifier:
      type: 'terminal-notifier'
  ...

production: &production
  process:
    notifier:
      type: 'airbrake'
      api_key: 'xxxx'
      host: 'xxx.xxx.com'
  ...
```

Is it reasonable to continue this practice with kubernetes and break the environments up in the `application.yml` or does kubernetes have some other best practices for provisioning structured configuration for pod?

Note that until all services are migrated, we basically have to hold the configurations as such:

```
kubernetes_staging:
  <<: *staging
  ...
```

Comment: Would it work to have a single config/application.yml file, and put that into your docker image, and use the same image for all types of pods, and then control which environment to use by varying the `-e` argument to rails?  Something like: 

   `.spec.container[].command: ["rails" "server" "-e", "production"]`

Comment: Thats basically what we we are doing right now. We specify the argument in the kubernetes configuration by setting the `RUN_ENV` environmental variable. So I guess staying with the rails way is the best practice?

Comment: I don't have any experience with Rails, so I can't speak to that.

Comment: We are planning a feature called "ConfigData" which will allow you to store files on the apiserver and mount them inside your containers.  That's issue https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/6477, thought it is a long one.  We also talked about something simpler, like this: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/13610  -- feel free to +1 on those issues if they look useful

Comment: Thanks Eric for your suggestions and the threads. It seems we are already following the best practices(basically as mentioned by you - a file in config/application.yml). The threads seem interesting, I will read them thoroughly and consider if it is worth it to move away from the current approach

Comment: Just a quick comment, use namespaces. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a few ways, one is keep doing what you're doing in a single file, another is to use labels to specify which environment's config to use, and the other is use namespaces.  I personally recommend namespaces, this way you can have separate `.yml` files for each environment that potentially spins up the same pods, but with different configurations, so to do this you would have staging, prod, etc namespaces.  Namespaces also are a great way to have the same kubernetes cluster have a concept of staging and production.  Additionally you can specify permissions for certain namespaces.

Here are the docs on namespaces https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/docs/design/namespaces.md